# Using XPath to retrieve elements inside a <script> tag

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to use XPath to get elements on a page which reside within a `<script>` tag. For example:

```
<div id="foo">
    <script>
        <p>You can't get me.</p>
    </script>
</div>
```

If I try `response.xpath('//div[@id="foo"]//p')` or `response.xpath('//div[@id="foo"]/script/p')`, both return an empty array.

How can I get the elements within the `<script>` tag using XPath?

Comment: Your XPath expressions are both ok. So there must be another error.

Comment: Really? I thought the `<script>` tag was to blame... Maybe I need to do some further debugging then.

Comment: I really do not know if the `<script>` tag is some kind of exception. If this is the case, my comment should be ignored.

Comment: I think this is the case [zx485](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305969/zx485). I just opened the element using the console and the script node don't contain any child nodes. It contains only text objects. Not HTML tags as nodes as one would normally expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy - how to convert string into an object which I can use XPath on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179732/scrapy-how-to-convert-string-into-an-object-which-i-can-use-xpath-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[eLRuLL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/858913/elrull) provided an even more elegant and better [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53179732/5753454) to my question. His solutions is as follows:

```
from scrapy import Selector

#First, retrieve the content within the <script> tag:
text = response.xpath('//script/text()').extract_first()
#Then, create a Selector
sel = Selector(text=text)
#Now we can use XPath normally as if the text was a common HTML response
sel.xpath(//p/text()).extract_first()
```

---

Old answer:
The `<script>` node has only text type children. That's why XPath don't get deeper down a `<script>` tag. But, I found a way around it.

```
#First, retrieve the content within the <script> tag:
text = response.xpath('//script/text()').extract_first()
#Then, encode it
text_encoded = text.encode('utf-8')
#Now, convert it to a HtmlResponse object
text_in_html = HtmlResponse(url='some url', body=text_encoded, encoding='utf-8')
#Now we can use XPath normally as if the text was a common HTML response
text_in_html.xpath(//p/text()).extract_first()
```