# Scrapy - how to convert string into an object which I can use XPath on?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Let's say I have some plain text in HTML-like format like this:

```
<div id="foo"><p id="bar">Some random text</p></div>
```

And I need to be able to run XPath on it to retrieve some inner element. How can I convert plain text to some kind of object which I could use XPath on?

Comment: Are you searching for Scrapy solution only?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that works with Scrapy. But it doesn't have to be Scrapy only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use a normal selector on which to run the same `xpath`, `css` queries directly:

```
from scrapy import Selector

...

sel = Selector(text="<div id="foo"><p id="bar">Some random text</p></div>")
selected_xpath = sel.xpath('//div[@id="foo"]')
```

Comment: That's definetely the easiest and most elegant solution. I wasn't aware about this Class. Just started with Scrapy a few days ago. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass HTML code sample as string to [lxml.html](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) and parse it with XPath:

```
from lxml import html

code = """<div id="foo"><p id="bar">Some random text</p></div>"""
source = html.fromstring(code)
source.xpath('//div/p/text()')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4549554/andersson) already posted a solution to my question. This is a second one which I just discovered that works as well and that uses Scrapy's classes, making it possible to use all methods already familiar to a Scrapy user (e.g., extract(), extract_first(), etc).

```
text = """<div id="foo"><p id="bar">Some random text</p></div>"""
#First, we need to encode the text
text_encoded = text.encode('utf-8')
#Now, convert it to a HtmlResponse object
text_in_html = HtmlResponse(url='some url', body=text_encoded, encoding='utf-8')
#Now we can use XPath normally as if the text was a common HTML response
text_in_html.xpath(//p/text()).extract_first()
```